# select statements in oracle with for read only

Tags: sql, oracle, readonly

I have a **Database Links** in **Oracle**, and when I query some data like: `select * from kfilwrk@something for read only`, I have an error: "missing keyword". I can just write select statement, but the problem is, I need to add `for read only` because my `select` statement may change some data.

UPD: when I write simple select statement and retrieve data, after that I close SQL Developer, it asks me to rollback or commit data. It means the select cursor updates some data

Comment: What makes you think queries (SELECT) change data? If you want, you can use [`SET TRANSACTION READ ONLY`](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e26088/statements_10005.htm#SQLRF55418) to ensure that no data is modified during transaction though.

Comment: @YasirArsanukaev, In an ANSI-compliant database, select cursors are update cursors by default. An update cursor is a cursor that can be used to modify data. These update cursors are incompatible with the read-only mode of the database.

Answer (score 2):

The syntax is `WITH READ ONLY`, not `FOR READ ONLY` and it can only be used with sub queries:

```
SQL> CREATE DATABASE LINK MyLink CONNECT TO HR IDENTIFIED BY HR USING 'sampleHost:1521/XE';
SQL> SELECT COUNT(*) FROM (SELECT * FROM Dual@MyLink WITH READ ONLY);

  COUNT(*)
----------
         1
```

See also http://docs.oracle.com/database/121/SQLRF/statements_10002.htm#SQLRF55295:

> *subquery_restriction_clause* The subquery_restriction_clause lets you restrict the subquery in one of the following ways:
>
> **WITH READ ONLY**  Specify WITH READ ONLY to indicate that the table or view cannot be updated.

Alternatively, you can set your transaction into read only mode:

```
SET TRANSACTION READ ONLY;      -- Read only
...
SET TRANSACTION ISOLATION LEVEL READ COMMITTED;   -- back to default (read committed)
```

Comment: This is not working, writes: SQL command not properly ended. I think it links with PRIVATE DATABASE LINKS where I query request

Comment: How exactly did you create the database link? It does work with simple links, see my updated answer

Comment: It is very interesting, when I rewrote my query like yours, with select count statements, it works well, but simple select doesn't. WTH?

Comment: Hmm, excuse me, but select count (*) also doesn't work, because after that query I closed the SQL Developer, and it asked me to rollback or commit data. It means the select statement cursor updated some data(

Comment: Seems that this only applies to the sub query cursor... have you tried the approach from @Yasir to set the transaction into read only mode?

Comment: I think you need to be more specific about your actual use case - can you provide a minimal example which reproduces the issue (including the necessary create table statements, some sample data (INSERT statments) and the query required to show the issue?

Comment: The problem is I didn't create that links. And there are no one who worked with that

Comment: I tried with set transaction read only, and when I close SQL Developer after the query, it says: connection has uncommitted changes.

Answer (score 0):

If you query over a DB_LINK the database assumes there are transactions to COMMIT on close.

Also, SQL Developer has a shared connection for the Worksheet and the Database Navigator/Object Editors. So if you had opened a table and changed a record - that's on the same connection as your SELECT query on the worksheet.